# Import error: no module named Num.msg

Tags: ros, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to use my own msg, and try this:

from Num.msg import *

and get the import error. Num.msg is in /msg/ and is found by "rosmsg show". When I don't import, codeline "a = Num()" gets error "Global name 'Num' is not defined". What do I miss?

Thanks,

hvn

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251500/import-error:-no-module-named-num.msg/) by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2017-01-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The python package for messages is named after the ROS package name, not the message name.

This means that the import syntax for a single message is:

```
from my_package.msg import MyMessage
```

Or for all messages in a package:

```
from my_package.msg import *
```

It looks like you should change `Num` to your package name. (note that package and message names are case-sensitive)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-01-08**:
Based on [your other question](http://answers.ros.org/question/251485/unable-to-load-msg-invalid-name/) ; the import should be `from robot_pi.msg import Num` or `from robot_pi.msg import *`

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2017-01-09**:
Ok, I've changed its name to robot_pi.msg, leaving its content intact: [code]int32[] data[/code]
Now I want to this for publishing: pub=rospy.Publisher('speaker', int32, queue_size=10)  a=robot_pi()  a.data=[1,2,3] and still get the errors. Where do I go wrong?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-01-09**:
The message name is `Num`, so use that when you create the publisher.

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2017-01-09**:
I changed Num.msg into robot_pi.msg and changed CMakelists.txt accordingly. New robot_pi.msg doesn't contain Num but "int32[] data". So how is the message name Num? I assume create the publisher is pub = rospy... so int32 should be replaced by the message name?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-01-09**:
Ok, if you're renamed your message file (that wasn't clear from your previous post), then the message name is now `robot_pi`.

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2017-01-09**:
Thank you. Now it works.

**Comment by [Rutvik](https://answers.ros.org/users/153261/rutvik/) on 2023-06-11**:
Hii, in my case it gives error that my_package.msg not found

my scripts folder is in the my_package folder